# memcached (spymemcached) counters and expiry time

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

can anybody tell me (or point to some documentation that documents) how memcached counters work? Specifically: how do they expire? I'm using the java spymemcached client.

The method

```
net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.incr(String key, int by, long def, int exp)
```

takes a parameter "exp" described as "the expiration of this object"

Does that mean each individual call to the counter has its own expiry time? Or does calling incr bump the expiry time for the key?

Also, shouldn't there be a method to get a counter value? Or should I call incr with an increment of 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `int exp` will overwrite the existing expiration time, and "bump" the key your incrementing. Check out the [protocol docs](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt#L79) for additional info.

> Also, shouldn't there be a method to get a counter value? Or should I
>   call incr with an increment of 0?

You can get the value of the counter cell by using `MemcachedClient.get` method. The counter cell will need to be set from `MemcachedClient.set` before you are able to increment it. I'm not 100% sure about [spymemcached](/questions/tagged/spymemcached), but some [memcached](/questions/tagged/memcached) libraries will auto set the counter cell to 0 -- before incrementation.

A note on expiration time. If the `int expr` is `-1` memcached will use the previous expiration time. If `int expr` is greater than `2592000` (30 days), it will be treated as an UNIX timestamp.

Comment: The mentioned protocol docs state that incr/decr do not receive expr parameter nor affect ttl in any way, which is a bit puzzling :)

Answer (score 0):

From [the comments in the source code](https://github.com/dustin/java-memcached-client/blob/953c322ad254bf6f544bac6738114176040a9c6f/src/main/java/net/spy/memcached/ops/MutatorOperation.java#L46) :

> get the expiration to set in case of a new entry.

So, I suspect that both the flags passed in `def` and the `expr` time are used only in case that the key is missing.

I find the code hard to follow, as I am not a Java programmer, but [this foo](https://github.com/dustin/java-memcached-client/blob/953c322ad254bf6f544bac6738114176040a9c6f/src/main/java/net/spy/memcached/MemcachedClient.java#L1949) seems to perform something like: if incr(key,value) fails, try to perform add(key,value,def,expr) and if this fails as well, then try incr(key,value) again.